# How can I update application?

Tags: 10.04, updates, downgrade

I had some problems with Ubuntu 11.10 (my PC is too old for it) and decided to downgrade to 10.04 LTS. Everything is fine except that all programs that are installed aren't up to date. For instance Rhythmbox says that databese was created by newer version of the program  and can't read it.
Update manager seems to find only system updates...

How do I update programs (Rhythmbox, Empathy etc) after downgrade?

Comment: you would be better placed to install a lighter-weight 11.10 distro such as xubuntu or lubuntu - you will have up-to-date packages out of the box!

Comment: (I know it's not topic related) I have two partitions one for root other for home. I want to format root partition but on /home there are application settings and other stuff. Won't it conflict with new Xubuntu/Lubuntu installation?

Comment: ordinarily it wouldnt matter too much - however there is a big jump between 10.04 using GTK+2 and GTK+3 - you probably will have issues just leaving /home.  Worth a try though... but I would do a drive image backup first so that you can get back to an initial starting point quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your PC is too old for 11.10, you should consider using a light weight distribution instead of downgrading to an older Ubuntu version. Try out lubuntu or xubuntu!

If you still want to your run newer programs on an older version of Ubuntu, this is possible but not relly the suggested way. A new version of Ubuntu is released every 6 months and that moment all programs are updated to an up to date version (not only the core system - but actually it's difficult to say what exactly is part of Ubuntu's core system and what are only extra programs). This enables developers to test if everything is working fine with the distributed programs for every Ubuntu version. Otherwise nobody could ensure that all the different versions of programs are compatible. Most GNU/Linux distributions do it that way. Only some provide also a not so stable branch with really up to date software.

So Ubuntu updates are primarily for security patches and bugs but not for new features. If you still want newer versions of some programs on and older version of Ubuntu, there are several ways to do so. Best would be to find [backports](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports). If there are no official backports you can add [repositories](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu). The worst would be to find a deb file or even a tar ball, but then you won't even get security updates.

Comment: I thought that Lubuntu and Xubuntu are so different from Ubuntu that programs I was using under Ubuntu won't work with them. Will they?

Comment: They will do, maybe some of them not so well integrated into your desktop environment. Maybe there are differences with panels, window decorations etc. So maybe Rhythmbox won't be integrated into the volume icon, but it will run. The easiest is to just try it out. Use a live CD (or even better USB stick if that works) and spend half an hour testing your common tasks. You can even install programs in your live system (although they are gone if you reboot of course, you can't save anything on a Live CD).

Answer (score 0):

Your PC is too old for it? How much RAM do you have? 1G should be enough.

An Ubuntu release contains all the applications you are talking about. To update to newer versions of individual applications, you'll have to find backports. There'll be [official backports](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports) for some packages, but not many. If there aren't official backports, you may be able to find PPAs with newer versions of applications, but the quality will vary and there are no guarantees (and probably no security support).

Comment: Yeah, 1 GB but it's shared with graphic card. Previos Ubuntu versions (those without Unity) where running fine. Since I had problems with turning off Unity in Ubuntu newset release I decided to try with diferent distribution.
I've installed Xubuntu and it works like a charm :)